# What is proper format for header files?

Tags: objective-c, header

I'm very new to iOS and object oriented programming. How should i use the format of the header files to help me? I have attached a blank header file of class NewClass which is a sub class of UIView Controller.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewClass : UIViewController

@end
```

What I would really like to know are where do I do certain things? Where do I declare variables and what types of variables? Where do I declare methods? Is there a difference of where I put private or public variables? Instance variables? Importing other things? How does the format help me and other readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface NewClass(class name) : UIViewController (type)
 {
  variables
 }

 methods

 @end
```

private methods and variables should go in the implementation file

more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

Comment: Note that declaration of ivars in the public header is pretty uncommon these days.

Comment: where do you put @property things?